# How to map function keys in less?

Tags: less

Is it possible to map function keys (F1-F12) in `less` with `lesskey`?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
#command
F1    forw-line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, [terminals use escaped sequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630) for functions keys, cursor keys and more. The termcap and terminfo facilities help to deal with the variations across terminals.

First you need  to determine what your terminal sends when you hit <kbd>F1</kbd>, in `bash` you can do:

`printf "%q\n" "`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>F1</kbd>`"`

Within the second pair of quotes you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to cause the next keystroke to be treated literally (*verbatim*), and then <kbd>F1</kbd>.
On my terminal (rxvt) I see

```
$'\E[11~'
```

so my F1 sequence is `escape [ 11 ~`, so into `.lesskey` should go

```
#command
\e[11~  forw-line
```

run `lesskey` to update, and now <kbd>F1</kbd> will invoke that command.

`infocmp` is another way to see how your terminal is set up, e.g.

```
infocmp -L1 rxvt | grep key_f1=
```

See Stéphane Chazelas [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76591/31352) for more details on that, though `less` doesn't use `readline`, configuring readline requires a similar understanding.